# Issue with definition of functions called by javaScript created buttons

Tags: javascript, html, json

Below i have code, where with JavaScript i make buttons and insert them into html. In that function i give every button the "onclick" command of onclick="start()". and the test that command with a console.log.

The issue arises when i add an imported Json file like "import test from 'test.js';" at the top. and add type="module" on the script tag in the html
After that no mater what button I click the onclick function becomes "Undefined".

I was wondering why and if there is a solve for this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>test</title>

        <script src="test.js" type="module"></script>
     </head>
        <body>
          <div id="titles">
                
          </div>
        </body>
  </html>
```

JavaScript ( as I said the issue is that the start function called by the onclick on the js created buttons doesnt work if the import on line 1 is there, but if you remove it it works fine.)

```
import test from './test.js';

const amountOfTitles = 5;

function createButtons(amountOfTitles){
    let buttons = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < amountOfTitles; i++){
        buttons += `<button id="${["name" + i]}" class="buttons" type="button" onclick="start()" >${["title" + i]}</button>`
    };
    document.getElementById('titles').innerHTML = buttons;
    return
};

function start(){
    console.log('test');
};

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    createButtons(amountOfTitles);
}, false);
```

JSON

```
const test = `{
    "test":[
    {"t":"1"}
]}`;

export { test as default };
```

Comment: That's not JSON... the `test` variable is a string that could be considered a "JSON string". It's unclear why you're defining it as a string though, because when you `include` it, you're going to have to run `JSON.parse(test)` on the resulting import. If you just removed the tick marks, you could `import` it and immediate use `test.test.t` and get back `"1"`.

Comment: I did not know that! thanks, though by tick marks i assume the ' on './test.js'; 
if that is what you mean then I get unexpected tokens from the ./ but even if i remove them then i get a Unexpected identifier? so im not sure what you mean

Comment: The `\`` character right after `const test =` and the one just before the semicolon in the "JSON" file.

Comment: could you provide a working demonstration? I cannot seem to do it? I must be failing at understanding your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the Console of your Dev Tools you would get an error and see you are having a problem with loading ES6 modules that are subject to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). You need to run your script from a local server, open directly the file with a browser will not work.

Recomended steps:

1. not sure what IDE you are using but try **Visual Studio Code**.
2. Open the IDE and find the Extensions tab (left side of screen -> tetris icon) or (Ctrl + Shift + X)
3. Search for and install **Live Server**
4. Press **Go Live** in VS Code bottom blue line right side
5. Enjoy coding =]

Comment: I am using VScode with the Live server extension to run my code, but thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is your issue but I noticed your doing string interpolation in a loop but not indicating you variable correctly.

Your doing:

```
 `<button id="${["name" + i]}" class="buttons" type="button" onclick="start()" >${["title" + i]}</button>`
```

It should be:

```
`<button id="${["name" + ${i}]}" class="buttons" type="button" onclick="start()" >${["title" + ${i}]}</button>`
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment i dint learn it this way, though it works without it. at least for what ever I'm using it for.